# Odoo 10 - QWeb hide a view element if a field is False

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have following QWeb element:

```xml
<record id="extended_res_partner" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Extended View</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="Foo" name="foo" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_customer', '=', False),]}">
                    <field name="is_customer" invisible="1"/>
                    <span>Foo2</span>
                </page>
            </notebook>
    </field>
</record>
```

But it does not work. I get:

```
Field `is_customer` does not exist
```

If I remove `attrs=...`  it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Even that you didn't provide the error message but this will work only if the the form view if for `res.partner` but i'm assuming that the form is for another model that have a many2one relation with `res.partner` in this case you need to create a related field in the model.

```
partner_id = ......
is_customer = fields.Boolean(related='partner_id.is_customer', readonly=True)
```

Then you need to add this field to the form view because attrs is client side feature it need the value in form in order to work.

```
<page string="foo" name="foo" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_customer', '=', False),]}"> 
    <field name="is_customer" invisible="1"/>
    <span>Foo2</span>
</page>
```

Note: if the form view is for `res.partner` just add the field to the form view because as I said is a client side operation it will not call the server to know what is the value of that field you need to pass it.

Comment: Cherif,  @bhavesh-odedra See edited question, still not working